# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function lang()

Tags: php, reactjs, function, lang

I need help with  the following part of the code:

```php
$RIPLE_NAV =array(
    array (
        'label' => lang('home'),
        'link' => '',
        'type' => 'public',
        'icon' => 'icon-home'
    ),
    array (
        'label' => lang('search'),
        'link' => '',
        'type' => 'public',
        'icon' => 'icon-search'
    ),
    array (
        'label' => lang('explore'),
        'link' => '',
        'type' => 'public',
        'icon' => 'icon-compass'
    )
    
);
```

when I try to use the function lang();, it show me the following errorFatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function lang() and I dont know what it could be the cause, any sugestions? thanks!

Comment: There's no such function as lang() in PHP unless it's a custom function. Remove the lang(). 
Looks like you're trying to make your site multilingual. With that, you've to state your question clearer with the full details

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
yeah later I review the code again and notice that I was typing wrong the function and now the error is not more

Comment: You should give me an upvote then

Comment: I am new at stack overflow, but I dont see the up arrow to give you an upvote, just your comment and a flag